# Javascript implicit object creation

Tags: javascript

What's the correct way to initialize an object in this setting:

```
for(var key in (assoc_array||{other.dict.id: other.dict})){

}
```

here I get an error that the dot in part "other.object.id" should not be there. So the way that works is:

```
var default_object = {}
default_object[other.dict.id] = other.dict;
for(var key in (assoc_array||default_object)){
  ...
}
```

There has to be a way to declare default object implicitly though?

Comment: Your second code is the only way to go I believe.You can't have dynamic key names declared like: `{other.dict.id: other.dict}`. Also are you trying to extend `assoc_array`?

Comment: Empty objects in JavaScript are truthy, just so you know.

Comment: No not to extend, but to initialize the array with a dynamic key name and value pair in as little code as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible like that,

you may have to use a function to do it

```
function createObj(key, val){
    var obj = {};
    obj[key]  = val;
    return val;
}

for(var key in (assoc_array||createObj(other.dict.id, other.dict))){

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RTn7w/)